# How to find keywords in multiple files which often appear together?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I want to find keywords, which often occur in relation to each other.

### Example

A directory contains markdown files, each with some keywords on the last line:

```bash
$ tail -n 1 file1.md
#doctor #donkey #plants

$ tail -n 1 file2.md
#doctor #firework #university

$ tail -n 1 file3.md
#doctor #donkey #linux #plants
```

##### Pseudo output

- 100% of the files containing the keyword "#donkey" also contain the keyword "#doctor".
- 50% of the files containing the keyword "#plants" also contain the keyword "#linux".
- …

---

A Shell script, an awk script, or just an explanation on how to achieve this goal would suffice!

**Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much**

Comment: Hi Luca! What you're asking for is a *clustering algorithm*; neither shells nor simple text-based processing tools like `awk` will get you very far here.

Comment: you could just build a large (lower traingular) table of keywords-vs-keywords and increase each (row n, column m) entry if the word in the nth row appears with the word in the word in the m'th column, and normalize by the total number of occurences of each word. Then, look for maximum subdiagonal elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using GNU awk for arrays of arrays:

If the keywords were on the first line of each file than also using GNU awk for `nextfile` for efficiency:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR == 1 {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        words[$i]++
        for ( j=i+1; j<=NF; j++ ) {
            pairs[$i][$j]++
            pairs[$j][$i]++
        }
    }
    nextfile
}
END {
    for ( word1 in pairs ) {
        for ( word2 in pairs[word1] ) {
            pct = pairs[word1][word2] * 100 / words[word1]
            printf "%d%% of the files containing the keyword \"%s\" also contain the keyword \"%s\".\n", pct, word1, word2
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file*.md
100% of the files containing the keyword "#university" also contain the keyword "#doctor".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#university" also contain the keyword "#firework".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#plants" also contain the keyword "#donkey".
50% of the files containing the keyword "#plants" also contain the keyword "#linux".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#plants" also contain the keyword "#doctor".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#donkey" also contain the keyword "#plants".
50% of the files containing the keyword "#donkey" also contain the keyword "#linux".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#donkey" also contain the keyword "#doctor".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#linux" also contain the keyword "#plants".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#linux" also contain the keyword "#donkey".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#linux" also contain the keyword "#doctor".
33% of the files containing the keyword "#doctor" also contain the keyword "#university".
66% of the files containing the keyword "#doctor" also contain the keyword "#plants".
66% of the files containing the keyword "#doctor" also contain the keyword "#donkey".
33% of the files containing the keyword "#doctor" also contain the keyword "#linux".
33% of the files containing the keyword "#doctor" also contain the keyword "#firework".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#firework" also contain the keyword "#university".
100% of the files containing the keyword "#firework" also contain the keyword "#doctor".
```

or on the last line then again relying on gawk for `ENDFILE`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
ENDFILE {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        words[$i]++
        for ( j=i+1; j<=NF; j++ ) {
            pairs[$i][$j]++
            pairs[$j][$i]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for ( word1 in pairs ) {
        for ( word2 in pairs[word1] ) {
            pct = pairs[word1][word2] * 100 / words[word1]
            printf "%d%% of the files containing the keyword \"%s\" also contain the keyword \"%s\".\n", pct, word1, word2
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file*.md
```

or still on the last line but more efficiently using tail+gawk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        words[$i]++
        for ( j=i+1; j<=NF; j++ ) {
            pairs[$i][$j]++
            pairs[$j][$i]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    for ( word1 in pairs ) {
        for ( word2 in pairs[word1] ) {
            pct = pairs[word1][word2] * 100 / words[word1]
            printf "%d%% of the files containing the keyword \"%s\" also contain the keyword \"%s\".\n", pct, word1, word2
        }
    }
}

$ tail -qn1 file*.md | awk -f tst.awk
```

Comment: even if you just did that guy's homework, I'm still amazed :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks! Every time I see a "this would be difficult with awk" type of comment I just can't help myself... :-).

Comment: ohhh, so [I nerd-sniped you](https://xkcd.com/356/)!

Comment: Exactly. I tried but just couldn't click away. If anyone every posts a comment that you can't prove the Riemann Hypothesis with awk I'm screwed.